# how to get the count of model related by foreignkey

Tags: python, django

say I have two models post and comment. I want to get the count of comment that's related to post by foriegnkey. I'm trying to list post by the order of comment. but I'm not sure how to get the count of comment related to each post.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and in views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'community/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 4
    #ordering = ['-#comment'] #how do I do this one?hmm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
post_pks = Post.objects.all().values('pk', flat=True)

post_comments = {}
for pk in post_pks:
    sorted_comments = list(Comment.objects.filter(post_id=pk).ordered_by('-pk'))
    post_comments[pk] = sorted_comments
```

Firstly I fetch the post pks and loop them to fetch all comments associated with each of them. These comments are sorted according to their pk and I create a dictionary with keys the post pks and values comment instances.

Comment: Any feedback please?